# Assigning a volatile rvalue

Tags: c++, volatile, rvalue

I don't understand why the following code doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Test(const Test&) {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Test& operator=(const Test&) {
        std::cout << "Assign Op" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Test& operator=(const volatile Test&) {
        std::cout << "Volatile Assign Op" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

volatile Test func() {
    Test a;
    return a;
}
int main() {
    Test b;
    volatile Test c;
    b = c; // this line is correct
    b = func(); // this line doesnt compile correct
    return 0;
}
```

the line:

```
    b = c; // this line is correct
```

While:

```
    b = func(); // this line doesn t compile
```

The compile complains about:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:31:14: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘b = func()()’
test.cc:31:14: note: candidates are:
test.cc:12:11: note: Test& Test::operator=(const Test&)
test.cc:12:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘volatile Test’ to ‘const Test&’
test.cc:17:11: note: Test& Test::operator=(const volatile Test&)
test.cc:17:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘volatile Test’ to ‘const volatile Test&’
```

In the beginning I thought that it was due to constructor elision, which I was experimenting how to disable it using volatile, when I got into this situation. Compiling with:

> -fno-elide-constructors

Didn't make any difference.

Any explanation for this?
Testing with:

> g++ (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)

Answer (score 4):

Per **[dcl.init.ref]**/5, for a reference (i.e. the parameter of `Test::operator=()`) to be initialized by binding to an rvalue, the reference must be a `const` non-`volatile` lvalue reference, or an rvalue reference:

> — Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be `const`), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.

The line `b = c;` works because you are binding a reference (the parameter of `Test::operator=()`) to an lvalue.

Comment: Could you please further explain? Here I m expecting an assignment operator to be called. Is there some way to force that? which signature this operator should look like?

Comment: @meodou assignment is subject to overload resolution (**[over.match]** /2) ; per **[over.match.oper]** /2 this is a call to the assignment operator function. Because the formal parameter of your assignment operator is a reference type, per **[over.match.viable]** /3 the reference must be bound to its argument; **[over.best.ics]** /1 refers back to **[dcl.init]**, and for reference type parameters **[dcl.init.ref]**.

Comment: @meodou you could try providing a volatile rvalue reference parameter: `operator=(T volatile&&)` or for full applicability a const volatile rvalue reference: `operator=(T const volatile&&)`. It is not possible to bind a lvalue reference to a volatile rvalue.