# Why a const volatile reference cannot be bound to an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to understand why a const volatile reference cannot be bound to an rvalue reference?
What is the rational reason to prohibit such a conversion?

In the following code I comment out lines that do not compile:

```
int main(){
 int i=1;
 //const volatile int& cvi2=std::move(i); -> ERROR: why?
 const volatile int i2=0;
 //const volatile int& cvi3=std::move(i2);// -> ERROR: why?
}
```

Here a more realistic scenario, that fails to compile for a similar reason:

```
#include<iostream>
template<class T> void g(const T& b){
  //do usefull things
}
template<class T,class F> void f(T& a,F a_func){
  //do usefull things with a
  a_func(std::move(a));
}
int main(){
   int i=0;
   volatile int vi=1;
   f(i,g<int>); //OK no error;
   f(vi,g<volatile int>);//ERROR: can not convert volatile int to
                                 //const volatile int &
 }
```

In this code, I would have expected that `g<volatile int>(const volatile&)` accept any argument.

An other edit, for a more concret example:

```
#include <vector>
using usefull_type=int;
void set_communication_channel_to(volatile usefull_type* g,size_t n);
int main(){
  auto vect=
    std::vector<volatile usefull_type>(10,usefull_type{42});//->ERROR no known conversion
                                                      // from int to const volatile int &
  set_communication_channel_to(vect.data(),vect.size());
  //... 
  //...
 }
```

There must have a good reason for this limitation no?

Comment: `const volatile` What should this mean??

Comment: all reads are observable behaviour?

Comment: Can you post just the minimal of lines to produce the error you misunderstand, with no comments?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048208/assigning-a-volatile-rvalue

Comment: My guess is that if you are trying to bind a const volatile ref to a rvalue you are probably doing something wrong. Therefore the standard forbids that for safety reasons. `volatile` expresses the fact that the value might be mutated by external causes (like other threads) which is in contradiction with the rule that only constant references can be bound to temporaries.

Comment: Leon understood what was my question. In fact I found this restriction while toying with function overloading. I guess we can have such a binding with some successives templates instantiation. I'll try to find an example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Maybe something like "data from external sources"?  If a program is intended to read, for example, data from a raw memory location, without actually _modifying_ that data, it would make sense for it to be `const volatile`; this situation probably comes up in drivers, I would imagine.  Alternatively, it could just be the end result of applying const correctness to something that was volatile to begin with.

Comment: @JustinTime `const` is `const` so I don't see any value regarding adding `volatile`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not very useful in most situations, I believe, but it does have its uses.  Mainly, `volatile` prevents the compiler from optimising out reads & conditions, guaranteeing that it'll be read again every time you want to read it; since the object is also `const`, any sane compiler would normally assume it can't be changed, and optimise accordingly if not for the `volatile` (likely by hard-coding the value it was initialised with every time you want to access it).

Comment: So, if you want to indicate that your program doesn't change it, but some external source _does_, you use `const volatile` to make sure that the compiler will make your program actually read it when you want to read it.  It's basically an inbox: People put letters in it for you, but you can't send any letters out by putting them in it; it would be kinda silly to say "Well, this inbox was empty when I bought it, so that means it'll never have any mail in it."

Comment: @JustinTime I know all of that. Though what the OP says that doesn't apply there. It's a simple const and volatile doesn't make sense.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My bad.  For some reason, I thought you meant in general.  In his example, whether there's value would depend on whether the variable is `volatile` to begin with.  It would also depend on what "useful things" `f()` and `g()` are actually supposed to do, and what the program is for; the example is too generic to make any assumptions about at the moment.

Comment: ^ That @JustinTime

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct question should sound as "**Why a const volatile reference cannot be bound to an rvalue**?"

The following code doesn't compile either, although no rvalue references are directly involved:

```
const volatile int& cvr = 0;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048551/6394138) to a related question cites the relevant section of the standard:

> Per **[dcl.init.ref]**/5, for a reference to be initialized by binding to an rvalue, the reference must be a `const` non-`volatile` lvalue reference, or an rvalue reference:
>
> > — Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be `const`), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.

My guess is that this restriction has historical roots in the C++98 standard where rvalues were limited to temporaries, that were fully managed by the compiler. The compiler can place the temporary at any address or register of its choice, and treating it as a volatile object with observable reads doesn't make sense. In the new standard an lvalue reference can be converted to an rvalue reference with `std::move()`, however as a result it gets the old properties assumed for rvalues, i.e. that their exact memory address is insignificant, and thus cannot have the volatile attribute assigned to it.

Technically this restriction is not a very limiting one, since you can effectively bind a `const volatile` reference to an rvalue through an extra level of indirection:

```
// This doesn't compile
// const volatile int& cvr = 0;

// This does compile
const int& cr = 0;
const volatile int& cvr = cr;
```

Comment: This was actually my question. Should I make an edit to change it?

Comment: @Oliv I think you should at least edit the title. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I did it, I kept the "bouding to rvalue reference", since it was actualy the correct phrasing of my question: you have rephrased and generalized the problem to any kind of rvalue (ref or not ref). So I just tried to pick the minimum of your answer to make my question understandable.

Answer (score 5):

The literal reason is that [dcl.init.ref] forbids such a declaration:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>   - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression [...]
>   - Otherwise, the reference **shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type** (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.

The next level reason is just a guess (and a problem with asking why questions): such a declaration makes no sense. The purpose of `volatile` is to make all reads and writes observable behavior. If you're initializing a reference to `const volatile` from a temporary, you're now the owner of the lifetime of this object. But you can't write to it. And neither can anyone else. So what does `volatile` convey?

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same point I made in my comment. If you really want you can still use `const volatile T&&`, which makes things more symmetric.

Comment: @M.M Yes I know. I even said that in the answer?

Comment: @Barry your last sentence asks "So what does volatile convey?" , my comment answers that.

Comment: @M.M: You should read all the sentences before that one, too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did. Which makes it puzzling why the author apparently has forgotten what volatile conveys by the time he wrote the last sentence.   Maybe it was meant to be a rhetorical question (implying that the author thinks volatile does not convey anything), but that would still suggest the author forgot or didn't understand what he just wrote.

Comment: @M.M: Yes, it's a rhetorical question, and one that — to me — makes perfect sense within the narrative of the answer. Perhaps you forgot, or didn't understand, that we are talking about `const volatile` _in the context of a lifetime-extending reference_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could you explain what meaning you took from the last sentence, in plain language?

Comment: @M.M. It's already in plain language. I see no value in repeating it if you didn't comprehend it the first time. I cannot help you resolve your misunderstanding without a better idea as to which part of the answer you misunderstood.

Comment: Rhetorical language isn't plain language. In plain language , asking a question means you are looking for an answer to that question.

Comment: @M.M. Then rewrite the rhetorical question to read "so `volatile` conveys no useful information here".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I's certainly useful information to the compiler and the programmer. Do you mean to suggest that removing `volatile` from the declaration would make no difference to the program? (Patently false)

Comment: @M.M It's not "patently false" and the information is not useful whatsoever. What other process or system can modify the data represented by the brand new temporary copy that is referred to by this reference?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Anything. That's what `volatile` says - may be modified by things outside of the program. Memory-mapped read-only hardware is a (relatively) common use case.

Comment: @M.M The point is that this kind of special use cases can't possibly apply to a temporary conjured by a compiler out of thin air.

Comment: @T.C. I don't see why not. A temporary with lifetime extended is basically the same as an object of the same storage duration as the reference. It will be able to access the read-only-but-changeable location etc. for the rest of its lifetime

Comment: @M.M: It will not be a read-only-but-changeable location, and it won't be a memory-mapped read-only hardware register. It's a temporary created by copy on that very line. It lives _solely_ within the C++ program. `volatile` may make sense on the thing it was copied from, but not on the copy. I don't know how else to put it to you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I don't know how else to put what is to me a simple concept either so maybe we'll have to end this "discussion" here.

Comment: @M.M: Your loss. :) Everybody else gets it.